# Get Sub Category List of a Current Category as Select option

Tags: category, category-tree

Currently in a Category view page, its sub categories are displayed in a list format. I would like to change the list to select option so when there are too many sub categories users does not have to scroll all the way to the bottom to view the content.

**Current Code:**

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name') ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

How can I accomplish this so the sub-categories is displayed in a select option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace that code with...

```
<?php if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCount() > 0) { ?>
    <select onchange="document.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('rel')">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
        <option rel="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name'); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

This will create a drop-down select box of the exact same categories that would have been displayed with the existing code, it will also navigate the user to the category when they click on a selection.

**EDIT: This is now TESTED AND WORKING code.**

Comment: @kane-show Your solution does works but the **empty select option appears on category page that does not have any sub category**. There must be a way to check if the category has active sub category and display accordingly using `if` statement? Very new to magento

Comment: Try this, I haven't tested it but let me know and I'll update my answer if it works.  At the beginning add `<?php if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories()) { ?>` and at the end add `<?php } ?>`

Comment: I don't think that comment will work. Try my updated answer.

Comment: @DNA I've just TESTED the code and updated my answer for the final time. USE THE UPDATED CODE, otherwise selecting options in the list wouldn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 4):

This might help you.

```
<select id="category" class="myinput-text required-entry widthinput" name="category">
<?php
  $parentid=5; // parent id which you want sub category
  $categories=explode(',',Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentid)->getChildren());
  foreach($categories as $cat){
  $category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
?>
<option value="<?php echo $category->getId();?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```